# How to remove Twitter Bootstrap (3.2) gradient in LESS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, linear-gradients

I was wondering if there was any way to remove Bootstraps gradient in .less files since I'm using .less files to theme my own application. I tried looking in variables.less or in mixins.less, but it just gets very confusing very fast.

I realized that when I'm in Chrome, I can remove the gradient by unticking linear-gradient, but I can't find it anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.
I changed my "Mixins/gradients.less" file to

```
#gradient {

  .horizontal(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%) {
    background-image: @start-color;
  }
  .vertical(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%) {
     background-image: @start-color;
  }
  .directional(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @deg: 45deg) {
    background-image: @start-color;
  }
  .horizontal-three-colors(@start-color: #00b3ee; @mid-color: #7a43b6; @color-stop: 50%; @end-color: #c3325f) {
    background-image: @start-color;
  }
  .vertical-three-colors(@start-color: #00b3ee; @mid-color: #7a43b6; @color-stop: 50%; @end-color: #c3325f) {
      background-image: @start-color;
  }
  .radial(@inner-color: #555; @outer-color: #333) {
    background-image: @inner-color;
  }
  .striped(@color: rgba(255,255,255,.15); @angle: 45deg) {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@angle, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%, @color 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@angle, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%, @color 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(@angle, @color 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, @color 50%, @color 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice choice. This solved my issue without destroying bootstrap pattern.